# How to restore Ubuntu server on a VMWare image after disk failure?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, restore

After a disk failure on a VMWare GSX I was able to start the raid with one disk and copy the VMWare image to my ESXi server. After repairing the image with

```
vmkfstools -x repair /vmfs/volumes/source/vmname/vmname.vmdk
```

and converting it to ESXi with

```
vmkfstools -i /vmfs/volumes/source/vmname/vmname.vmdk /vmfs/volumes/dest/vmname/vmname.vmdk -d thin
```

I am not able to boot the image an just get

```
GRUB Loading stage1.5.

GRUB loading, please wait...
_
```

and the cursor does not even blink.

What are my options now? Is it possible to recover somehow with a rescue CD? What are the steps?

UPDATE:

I followed the advice to create a new Ubuntu server and add the VMWare image as new disk. However I get the following.

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
 missing codepage or helper program, or other error
 In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
 dmesg | tail or so
```

I was trying to restore the superblock but had no luck with the following commands.

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdb
```

The above printed several numbers (as described in http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/).

```
e2fsck -b 20480000 /dev/sdb
```

I just keep getting "The superblock could not be read...". Do I have any chance to get the data on this ext3 file system back?

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu as a fresh VM, then mount the vmdk from the failed system as an additional disk.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea. I hope I can access needed data from it. Does it make sense to also try the rescue system option of a Ubuntu live CD?

Comment: If you really have to "recover" it, i.e. make the actual same image bootable again, then yea, probably run the rescue process. Otherwise, just copy off your configs and data and you are all set (I've found that this tends to get much more reliable and consistent results, and I don't end up spending hours troubleshooting weird boot parameters and grub issues that I don't really understand.)

Comment: Do you by any chance can help with the superblock issue from my UPDATE?

Comment: You probably need to mount specific partitions: "/dev/sdb3" or similar. Try "sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb" to see what might be available.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://linuxhint.com/fix-broken-ubuntu-without-reinstalling/

Comment: Also this: https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/